# publish a version of unchanged lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, boto3

I am trying to publish a version even if code or config has not changed. As per documentation this is not possible...

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.publish_version

> Lambda doesn't publish a version if the function's configuration and
> code haven't changed since the last version. Use UpdateFunctionCode or
> UpdateFunctionConfiguration to update the function before publishing a
> version.

I will like to know if there is any other (unofficial) way to publish a version of unchanged lambda function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Lambda [alias](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-aliases.html) is the standard way to get a durable additional reference to a function version.  A function alias, which has its own ARN, points to a specific version.

Pass the target version's ARN to the boto3 [create_alias](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.create_alias) method.

Comment: I considered that. But function URL always points to latest version (only).

Comment: @shantanuo -  [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-urls.html) _You can apply function URLs to any function alias, or to the $LATEST unpublished function version. You can't add a function URL to any other function version_.  Pass `Qualifier=MY_ALIAS` to [create_function_url_config](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.create_function_url_config).